# Median in Pivot in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I am trying to find median in the pivot block but i keep on getting the below error as pivot needs aggregate function. I thought median is an aggregate function.

Below is the code that I am using :-

```
select * from (
SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_KEY,
   SUM(ACCT_CURR_AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY trunc(execution_local_date_time,'mm'), ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_KEY,GROUP_TRANSACTION_TYPE_CD ORDER BY trunc(execution_local_date_time,'mm')) AS SUM_OVER_MONTH,
   COUNT(account.ACCOUNT_KEY ) OVER (PARTITION BY trunc(execution_local_date_time,'mm'), ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_KEY,GROUP_TRANSACTION_TYPE_CD ORDER BY trunc(execution_local_date_time,'mm')) AS COUNT_OVER_MONTH,
   GROUP_TRANSACTION_TYPE_CD                   
FROM CDS_SCHEMA.V_ACCOUNT ACCOUNT 
LEFT JOIN V_TRANSACTIONS TRA ON TRA.ACCOUNT_KEY = ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_KEY and EXECUTION_LOCAL_DATE_TIME BETWEEN '01-JAN-2019' and '30-JUN-2019'
JOIN CDS_SCHEMA.SAM_TRANS_CODE_TYPE_REL TRANS_CODE ON TRA.TRANSACTION_CODE_CD = TRANS_CODE.TRANSACTION_CODE_CD
JOIN CDS_SCHEMA.SAM_TRANS_TYPE_GROUP_REL TRANS_CODE_GRP ON TRANS_CODE_GRP.TRANSACTION_TYPE_CD = TRANS_CODE.TRANSACTION_TYPE_CD AND  TRANS_CODE_GRP.GROUP_TRANSACTION_TYPE_CD IN('EFT-INN','EFT-OUT','IFT-INN','IFT-OUT','CCE-INN','CCE-OUT','ALL-INN','ALL-OUT')
where ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_KEY = '0004447887C1CB00293D55CD3ED1D7B6CB3FE71C'
)a 
PIVOT 
(
    median(SUM_OVER_MONTH) *as* med_val, median(COUNT_OVER_MONTH) as med_vol
    FOR GROUP_TRANSACTION_TYPE_CD
    IN('EFT-INN','EFT-OUT','IFT-INN','IFT-OUT','CCE-INN','CCE-OUT','ALL-INN','ALL-OUT')
)
```

In the pivot block I keep getting error on "as". Kindly help me find median in pivot

Comment: MEDIAN can be used as an aggregate function. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the PIVOT part. Please remove the word PIVOT and everything after it and try to execute the query.

Comment: @StewAshton I have to use pivot as I have to get medians for every GROUP_TRANSACTION_TYPE_CD as column name. Is there an alternative for that

Comment: Please just do what I ask and post the error message if any. This is for debugging purposes only.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] including DDL statements for your tables, DML tables for some sample data and your expected output so that we can execute your query and know what it should do. Without that you've given us a block of code that we can only eyeball but cannot run and that makes helping you a lot more difficult; so please take the time to write a decent question and help us to help you.

Comment: Median works fine in pivot. See this demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f12c22e9f783af661c0ec96346cecdd5

Comment: Also let us know the exact error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

> In the pivot block I keep getting error on "as". Kindly help me find
>   median in pivot

Change the `*as*` to `as` in your `pivot` clause, i.e. instead of

```
median(SUM_OVER_MONTH) *as* med_val, median(COUNT_OVER_MONTH) as med_vol
```

write

```
median(SUM_OVER_MONTH) as med_val, median(COUNT_OVER_MONTH) as med_vol
```